# Batch file if exist is exiting the program when using %USERPROFILE%

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Basically, I am making a server and I am helping my friends join it (Don't Judge just felt like a game of Minecraft lmao) so I wanted to make a .bat file to do it automatically (slightly) and this it so far but when I get to the if exist the command prompt just exits any ideas?

```
@echo off
echo Hello there 
timeout 2
echo Do not close this down if it tells you not to!!
timeout 2
echo click any key to download the program 
start chrome.exe http://launcher.technicpack.net/launcher4/355/TechnicLauncher.exe
ping localhost -n 3 >nul 
echo star my github project pls 
start chrome.exe https://github.com/HawkSP/HawkSP.github.io
echo this next command is now going to wait for u game to download 
pause
if exist %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\TechnicLauncher.exe (
    pause
    start %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\TechnicLauncher.exe
    ping localhost -n 3 >nul
    echo click install
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    echo wait
    ping localhost -n 3 >nul
    echo enter Mojang Account email
    ping localhost -n 3 >nul
    echo enter Mojang Account Password
    echo dont click continue if you havent entered ur details
    pause
    echo CLICK "MODPACKS"
    timeout 2
    echo Cick on the "Add Pack or Search"
    timeout 1
    echo TYPE "HEXXIT" INTO THE BOX"
    timeout 2
    echo Hit "Enter"
    timeout 2
    echo Hit "Install"
    echo There will now be a 30 second time out
    timeout 30 
    echo When your ready for the next step click enter
    pause
    echo Click Multiplayer
    timeout 3
    echo Direct Connect or Add Server
    timeout 2
    echo Enter this IP
    timeout 1
    echo 
    timeout 5 
    echo congrats you have done it :)))
    pause


) else (
    pause
)
```

I have tried putting it in " " too

Answer (score 0):

#### When I get to the `if exist` the command prompt just exits

```
echo congrats you have done it :)))
```

The above statement contains `)` characters which prematurely terminates  your `if` ... statement

Replace with

```
echo congrats you have done it :^)^)^)
```

where `^` is an escape character.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.
- [syntax-brackets](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html) - Using parenthesis/brackets to group expressions